# Extracting Information from XML in SQL Server after performing a join

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a SQL table create through the following code with the column `UserDefinedXML` that contains a information I need to be able to extract.

```
SELECT A.ExternalID, A.UserDefinedXML, A.ServiceSiteUid, A.LastModifiedDate, A.PersonUid,
       B.FirstName, B.LastName, B.PersonUid,
       C.Name
  FROM Patient A
  INNER JOIN Person B ON B.PersonUid = A.PersonUid
  INNER JOIN ListServiceSite C ON C.ServiceSiteUid = A.ServiceSiteUid
  WHERE A.UserDefinedXML IS NOT NULL
  ORDER By LastModifiedDate
```

[image]

I have been extracting it through a lot of gsubs in R but that is inefficient and not the best way to go about it, I'm sure. The XML  format is below

```
<data>
  <LOA>
    <NotMedNecessaryInsCompany ControlType="PrmTextBox" Value="" Label="" />
    <DicontinuedDate ControlType="FindDateBox" Value="" Label="" Display="false" />
    <ReceivedDate ControlType="FindDateBox" Value="" Label="" Display="false" />
    <SentDate ControlType="FindDateBox" Value="" Label="" Display="false" />
    <ReasonDiscontinued ControlType="PrmTextBox" Value="" Label="" />
    <NoOONBenefitsInsCompany ControlType="PrmTextBox" Value="" Label="" />
    <InsuranceStatus ControlType="PrmGroupBox" Label="" Value="" />
    <OtherReasonDenied ControlType="PrmTextBox" Value="" Label="" />
    <FacilityRefused ControlType="PrmCheckBox" Value="false" Label="Facility Refused" />
    <ReasonDenied ControlType="PrmCheckBox" Value="false" Label="Other" />
  </LOA>
  <Forms>
    <POReceivedDate ControlType="FindDateBox" Value="" Label="" Display="false" />
    <InformedConsentReceivedDate ControlType="FindDateBox" Value="" Label="" Display="false" />
    <AuthorizationToTreatReceivedDate ControlType="FindDateBox" Value="" Label="" Display="false" />
  </Forms>
  <Skin_Sheet>
    <SkinSheet ControlType="PrmGroupBox" Label="No" Checked="PrmRadioButton1" Value="" />
  </Skin_Sheet>
</data>
```

For the moment, I am just interested in whether "Yes" or "No" is selected in the last few lines under the `SkinSheet` header. Ultimately, I will need to be able to access all of the fields in this string. Unfortunately I am very inexperienced with SQL and have been thrown into it at work so I am trying to learn on the fly.

Comment: Have you had a look at XQUERY? [xml Data Type Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-type-methods?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: On a different note [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). Using aliases like `A`, `B`, `C`, just makes things far harder, especially when you're referencing the same objects in different queries in different orders. You're very likely to end up with queries where every object has a different alias, yet the same 3/4 objects are referenced in theose 3/4 queries you have open. Making things really confusing not just for you, but any one else who has to read your SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `UserDefinedXML` is XML datatype, just use the [`value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) function:

```sql
SELECT A.UserDefinedXML.value('(//SkinSheet/@Label)[1]', 'varchar(100)'), other, columns
FROM ...
```